# how to send remote AT command to xbee device using python digi-xbee library

Tags: python, xbee

as the title said, i'm looking for a way to send an AT command to a remote xbee and read the response.
my code is in python and i'm using digi-xbee library.

another question: my goal of using AT command is to get the node ID of that remote xbee device when this last one send me a message, i don't want to do a full scan of the network, i just want to get its node id and obviously the node id doens't come within the frame. so i had to send to it an AT command so he send me back its node ID. if you have any suggestions that may help, please tell me, i'm open to any helpful idea.

PS. i tried to use read_device_info() within the callback function that launch when a data received but it didn't work. it works outside the function but inside no!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

when you recive a message you get an xbee_message object, first you must define a data receive callback function and add it to device . In that message you call remote_device_get_64bit_addr().

Comment: thank you for your answr, but that's not my question, i already know that and i did it, it's in their documentations and examples, my problem here, how i send an AT cmd, ( by the way, i looked at the xbee documentation and apparently its node id doesn't come with the frame in API mode, only data, or if i send at cmd " NI " to get it's node id)

Comment: I am also stucked looking how to send AT commands using the API, also can´t get the rssi value of the messages, have you achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to send a command to a remoted xbee: First, connect to the local XBee and then send a command to the local Xbee so the local Xbee can send a remote_command to the remoted XBee.

Here are the details:

1. Create a bytearray of the command. For e.g:

My command is: `7E 00 10 17 01 00 13 A2 00 41 47 XX XX FF FE 02 50 32 05 C5`, generated using XCTU. It is a remote AT command to set the pin DIO12 of the remoted XBee to `digital out, high [5]`. Create a raw bytearray of it.

> `raw = bytearray([0x7E,0x00,0x10,0x17,0x01,0x00,0x13,0xA2,0x00,0x41,0x47,0xXX,0xXX,
>                      0xFF,0xFE,0x02,0x50,0x32,0x05,0xC5])`

2. Create a packet: using `from digi.xbee.packets.common import RemoteATCommandPacket`

> `ATpacket = RemoteATCommandPacket.create_packet(raw, OperatingMode.API_MODE)`

3. Send the packet to the local XBee:

> `device.send_packet(ATpacket)`

Bonus: A more simple way to create a packet:

> `ATpacket = RemoteATCommandPacket(1,XBee16BitAddress.from_hex_string("0013A2004147XXXX"),XBee16BitAddress.from_hex_string("FFFE"),2,"P2",bytearray([0x05]))`

Comment: Hi.
i'm not sure if you get my question right or i didn't make it clear. but as far as i know when a remote xbee send a message, it doesn't include it's node ID in the packet, it only contains its address 64. so they are no way to know it's node ID from the message it send. the only way i figure it out is to ask him that by sending an AT command ask of its node ID. and that's all, 
and that's how i solved my problem.
any way, thank you

Comment: Hi, I've just read your question again and yes, I didn't get it fully. Because your title is _"How to send remote AT command"_ and you said _"when this last one send me a message"_ so I thought you want to send a remote AT command to the remote Xbee that you just received the message from. By the way, you solved it. Congrats.